# How to compile and install kernel.org kernel on a separate partition and then setup dual boot

Tags: kernel, grub2, dual-boot, initramfs

That question: [Compiling and installing a kernel.org kernel to a custom volume on disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28829/compiling-and-installing-a-kernel-org-kernel-to-a-custom-volume-on-disk) partially answers my question, however, not completely!

I have a disk with 30GB capacity. It has 2 partitions

- 2GB partition (`/dev/sda1`) which contains Debian
- 28GB partition (`/dev/sda2`) which is completely empty (formatted, filesystem is `ext4`)

I want to compile and install kernel.org kernel (https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.10.78.tar.xz) on `/dev/sda2` and setup dual boot between my Debian and new kernel

So far:

I mounted my second partition to `/mnt` (i.e. `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`) and created a directory `/src` within it (i.e. I have `/mnt/src` directory)

When in `/mnt/src`,

I downloaded the kernel and extracted it

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.10.78.tar.xz
unxz -v linux-5.10.78.tar.xz
tar xvf linux-5.10.78.tar
```

I also installed the necessary tools to be able to compile and install the kernel

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev
```

When in `/mnt/src/linux-5.10.78`

I copied my existing Debian kernel configuration to the current directory (i.e. `cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config`) and then ran `make olddefconfig` (with the idea to use my existing configuration and provide default values for everything else). I also unchecked the `Avoid speculative indirect branches in kernel` option because I hit `You are building kernel with non-retpoline compiler, please update your compiler..  Stop.` during `make`.

I then ran `make -j 4` again and waited for it to finish.

After that I ran `INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/mnt INSTALL_PATH=/mnt/boot make modules_install` to install the necessary modules, following the suggestion from the question I have linked above.

My problem is that now when I run `update-initramfs` it fails as it can't find a `/lib/modules/5.10.78` folder. That would obviously be the case as it is under `/mnt/lib/modules/5.10.78`. I tried providing different root path (using the `-b` option) but that didn't work. I also tried `chroot`, however, I don't really have the necessary setup/ executables in `/mnt` to `chroot` into it.

After "fixing" above, I expect running `update-grub` would discover the kernel image, the root filesystem for booting it and the configuration files and setup everything so that after reboot I am provided with both booting options (Debian and the new kernel).

Any help with both `update-initramfs` and the actual grub configuration afterwards would be greatly appreciated! I have found links here and there but they are always very high level overview of the process.

Comment: Could you precise your aim ? At no point you used a `debootstrap` or other command to load the target partition with an other system. If you do it, you will be able to type `chroot /mnt` and be able to use `update-initramfs`. Note that some directory should be mounted to some of the `/mnt/*` (dev, sys, proc). If you don’t want an other copy of Debian, grub should manage other kernel in its `/boot` directory.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer My aim is to build a custom minimal (in terms of drivers and features) linux distribution from source and be able to use it as booting option (should allow normal usage as OS - eg hardware drivers and filesystems support). First time I am hearing about `debootstrap`. What does it do exactly? I haven't seen it referenced in any of the articles I have read (e.g. https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html, https://phoenixnap.com/kb/build-linux-kernel, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115620/configuring-compiling-and-installing-a-custom-linux-kernel, etc).

Comment: Deboostrap is a Debian installer which install the minimum Debian system which can have a functional `apt` system and can load other package afterwards. It can be useful to build container images. As a Debian system it may not be minimal is the way you think. Note : the initramfs is needed for kernel with complex booting procedure (root on RAID filesystem). For a minimal system, you don’t need it.

Comment: initrd is needed if you need to load drivers before mounting root.  Typical candidates are video and disk (raid) drivers.  If you don't need to do that, it is possible to skip initrd and just jump directly into the real root.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, user10489, I don't really have a hard requirement on specifics. I just want to be able to boot using the new kernel, see a terminal, have the expected unix-like filesystem structure and be able to perform the standard commands. Of course, while keeping my other, Debian, partition completely isolated. Want to be able to choose either one at boot time. Can you, by any chance, provide me with specifics on how to achieve that?

Comment: With debootstrap, you typically type `debootstrap buster /mnt`… and you get a minimal system on `/mnt`. It doesn’t install the kernel, but you have installed it there.

Now, add an entry in grub to load the kernel, and use `/dev/sda2` as root.

Comment: If you want to learn how things work at a bit more low level by doing the full install by hand from source, check out the Linux From Scratch documentation.  I did it 20 years ago and learned TONS.  Most of which has been obsoleted by things like systemd and such :(

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to install a minimal Debian system is `debootstrap bullseye /mnt` where bullseye is the release you seek, and `/mnt` the path where you want it to be installed.

It needs a kernel, and your procedure seems correct. Initramfs or initrd is only required for complex boot sequence : typically a root directory in a RAID array. I have none on my server and it works fine. (Note that your root filesystem type mustn’t be compiled as a module but embedded in the kernel).

You should also add an entry in your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Typically :

```
menuentry "Alternate Debian , kernel 5.10.78" {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos2'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.78 root=/dev/sda2 ro  
}
```

`insmod part_msdos` is needed if you have an old partition scheme. On UEFI system, it should be `insmod part_gpt`, but I don’t know them much. `insmod ext2` permits grub to read an ext2 (or ext4) file system.
`set root=` indicates on which partition grub should search /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.78 (check the actual name : it may vary), `linux` indicate it should boot the kernel which follows, `root=/dev/sda2` indicates your future root directory.

If you really want a more tiny alternative system, perhaps Gentoo is a better way, but I know it only by name. You should start with `debootstrap`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I feel like using `debootstrap` would be circumventing my initial goal which is to see how things work a bit more low level. Why do I need it to boot from my kernel image?

Comment: You said __Of course, while keeping my other, Debian, partition completely isolated__. I guess the isolation you want imply installing a whole alternative system. If you just want another kernel, I see no interest to put it on /dev/sda2 and keep root on /dev/sda1. Perhaps I have not understood your intents. « Why do I need it to boot from my kernel image? ». The idea of booting on your compiled kernel is yours. And `debootstrap` doesn’t install a kernel, then using your compiled kernel is interesting. But you can use the kernel from /dev/sda1 with the /dev/sda2 root filesystem.

Comment: Yes, I meant installing a whole alternative system which is really minimal (basically, after boot, provides you with a terminal, file system support, drivers for working with disks etc). Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: A whole system seems to include the kernel, and debootstrap install the remaining of a minimal system, but minimal in a Debian way (with all things needed to add or configure other packages). This means 154 packages, 332MB for buster. You should start with this way before trying a more complex installation. Afterwards, perhaps you should have a look to Gentoo.